# Why is the `IDictionary.Values` property of type `ICollection`?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, icollection

I'm trying to wrap my head around why the `IDictioary<TKey, TValue>.Values` property is of type `ICollection<TValue>` as opposed to `IEnumerable<TValue>`. The .NET implementation of the `Values` property implements the interface property explicitly and then exposes the `Values` property as type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` which throws an exception when you try to add or remove values from it.

This seems like a complete hack. Because of the nature of a dictionary, does it ever make sense to create an implementation which allows you get get a collection of the values in the dictionary and add / remove values from it?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118451/difference-between-various-collection-generic-interfaces-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This allows you to use the `Count` property and the `Contains()` method on a dictionary interface.

You're right; it is an ugly hack.
The ideal soltuion would have been to use the new (to .Net 4.5) [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx).

Comment: +1: Furthermore, you wouldn't want to allow `Add` & `Remove` methods on the value collection because the Key would be null.

Comment: Why should the value collection have a `Contains` method?  `Count` is the only one that makes sense to me.

Comment: +1: It should have been `IReadOnlyCollection`, but it didn't exist at the time, and now they're stuck.

Comment: Just for fun, can you think of a Dictionary implementation which may benefit from being able to add/remove Keys/Values independently from the dictionary itself like the current interface technically supports?

Comment: Well, `ICollection<T>` has a property [`IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) for that

Comment: Do you check `IsReadOnly` before you add to any ICollection (as in, any list, or collection, etc)? If something's read only, why bother having methods that imply otherwise? Hence, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. It was long overdue.

Comment: @ColeCameron Tecnically you should. Anyway, I agree that `IReadOnlyCollection<>` is more suitable.